# Does NHibernate have a feature to Create and Update Tables, like EF Code First does Automatic Migrations?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, migration

I am using NHibernate and Fluent NHibernate for the first time. I had to physically create the database and write SQL scripts for the first 2 tables. Now, i am wondering if this technology (NHibernate), like Entity Framework (Code First) when you have enabled migrations has a similar too to create and update tables?

[This is what i mean by Ef Code First Automatic Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nHibernate` does support schema changes using `SchemaUpdate`

See: [Is NHibernate SchemaUpdate safe in production code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065845/is-nhibernate-schemaupdate-safe-in-production-code)

You can also generate a create script to execute against your database using `nHibernate SchemaExport`.

`SchemaUpdate` is not recommended for production use because of the security privileges that have to be granted in order for this to work. Personally I think you should look at a code based migrations tool which are designed to handle initial database creates plus full revision control, I use `Migrator.NET` - [Database migration in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219461/database-migration-in-c-sharp/16588848#16588848)

Comment: I like the idea of Database Migration. Loved it when i worked with Ruby on Rails. However, Migrator.Net doesn't get updated as much so i will try to replicate the idea with Fluent Migrator. http://nuget.org/packages/FluentMigrator/1.1.1.0

Comment: @KomengeMwandila absolutely any migration tool is a useful companion, I particularly like being able to roll the database forward (up) and backward (down) to version match the code-base.

Comment: I fail to update my schema, can you look at my question here please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63368078/nhibernate-not-detecting-schema-changes-how-to-update